# ExpandableListView OnGroupCollapseListener -any listener/observer for BEFORE the collapse happens?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

ExpandableListView has a listener for detecting when a group is collapsed called OnGroupCollapsedListener ([doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener.html)). Whatever code you put in this listener is invoked AFTER the group is collapsed.

Does anyone know how I can invoke some code BEFORE the group is collapsed??? Perhaps a BeforeCollapsedListener???

Comment: Need some more information. What you actually want to do???

Comment: I need to run some code before a group collapses after the user clicks the group header to initiate the collapse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this short snippet to save the group states and check them every time a group is clicked. Group click is registered before a group is expanded and/or collapsed.

```
private boolean[] mGroupStates;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    mGroupStates = new boolean[mExpAdapter.getGroupCount()]

    mExpList.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPos, long id) {
            // Switch boolean
            mGroupStates[groupPos] = !mGroupStates[groupPos];
            // Check expanding or collapsing
            if (mGroupStates[groupPos]) {
                // group is being expanded
            } else {
                // group is being collapsed
            }
            // False will make sure that the click continues with it's operation
            return false;
        }
    });
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the onGroupClickListener to trigger the collapsing / expanding yourself

```
ExpandableListView lv ; // init the listView with your stuff
boolean animated = true;
lv.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
            // do your stuff

            lv.expandGroup(groupPosition, animated);
            // let system handle event
            return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Apollo. user3249477 basically said the same thing before you did but didn't have the expandGroup part. Thanks again!

Comment: @TheHungryAndroider What if the group is expanded? You tell the list to expand it and collapse it at the same time. Funny that this is the *correct answer*.

Comment: For collapsing I just do .collapseGroup instead. I used a piece of both of your answers to be honest. I could only award one correct answer though :S

Comment: @TheHungryAndroider I'll award the other one when this bounty expires. They are both good answers. :)

Comment: @TheHungryAndroider if you are handling the expanding/collapsing yourself, you should also `return true;` so the system doesn't do it again, otherwise it may lead to the children being added twice.

Comment: Thanks, I did that :)

Comment: Thanks @Vikram I really didn't know what to do. I gave this chap the bounty to help his rep, but gave the correct answer to the other answer.

Comment: @TheHungryAndroider well the code of this answer actually bugs the list :) Dunno why it's getting upvoted or why you gave him the bounty. But you know best, since you're the OP.

Comment: @TheHungryAndroider Its fine, I've started a bounty for user3249477's answer.